React Native CLI Project SQlite problem NativeDatabase.prepareSync' has been rejected
I am working on a React Native CLI project where I am trying to connect to a database.db file. Despite several attempts, I keep encountering an error message stating that no such table:information. I have existing code that successfully connects to a SQLite database, and I’m now importing a new table into the same database. While the previous database tables work as expected, the newly imported tables are not recognized, and I receive a "Call to function NativeDatabase.prepareSync has been rejected Caused by: Error Code: no such table:information" error.
I have index.tsx file and following code:
export default function Tab() {
  const data = tableInformation();
  console.log(data)
}

and dbHandler.js file have following code:
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const openDatabase = () => {
  const db = SQLite.openDatabaseSync('database2.db');
  return db;
}

const  tableInformation = () => {
    const db = openDatabase();
    const data = db.getAllSync("Select * from information")
    return data;
}

export { tableInformation };

I get following error in console:
ERROR  Error: Call to function 'NativeDatabase.prepareSync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: Error code ☺: no such table: information
This error is located at:
in Tab
in Unknown (created by Route(explore))
in Suspense (created by Route(explore))
in Route (created by Route(explore))
in Route(explore) (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Screen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
in BottomTabNavigator
in Unknown (created by TabLayout)
in TabLayout
in Unknown (created by Route((tabs)))
in Suspense (created by Route((tabs)))
in Route (created by Route((tabs)))
in Route((tabs)) (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator
in Unknown (created by RootLayout)
in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayout)
in RootLayout
in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator
in Unknown (created by RootLayout)
in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayout)
in RootLayout
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator
in Unknown (created by RootLayout)
in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayout)
in RootLayout
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator
in Unknown (created by RootLayout)
in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayout)
in RootLayout
in Unknown (created by RootLayout)
in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayout)
in RootLayout
in RootLayout
in Unknown (created by Route())
in Suspense (created by Route())
in Route (created by Route())
in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
in wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (created by App)
in App (created by ErrorOverlay)
in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
in ErrorOverlay (created by withDevTools(ErrorOverlay))
in withDevTools(ErrorOverlay)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
